# Style override in react styled components

Tags: reactjs

I just started learning react and I am just confused that what is the best approach to make a common style for a button (something like base button).

I though to make a Button component and this is how it turned out to be.

```
import React from 'react';
import './Button.css';


type Props = {
    onClick: () => void,
    className: string
};

function Button({onClick, className}: Props) {
    return (
        <button onClick={onClick} className={className}/>
    );
}

export default Button;
```

I want some styles to be base and take others as props also I want an API to override the base styles in case there's any use case (hypothetically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use styled components to create a global Button component

```js
import styled from 'styled-components'

export const StyledButton=styled.button`
    //your styles
`
```

```js
import {StyledButton} from './StyledButton.jsx'

function App({onClick,className}: Props) {
    return (
        <StyledButton onClick={onClick} className={className} />
    );
}
```

**You can also pass props to styled components and render button conditionaly**

```js
const StyledButton = styled.button`
    padding: 2px 5px;
    color: ${props => props.color ? props.color : "white"};
    border-radius: 3px;
`

function App({onClick,className}: Props) {
    return (
        <StyledButton onClick={onClick} color={className.color} />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at some famous React UI library (antd, MU ...), and see how they implement base button
example: [antd](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/button/button.tsx)